# Может ли функция не иметь имени?

Tags: c++

Может ли функция не иметь имени?

Comment: Заголовок вопроса делайте более содержательным

Comment: А теперь попробуйте развернуть поподробнее вопрос.

Answer (score 5):

Вряд ли это то, что вас интересует, но в DLL функция может идентифицироваться не только по имени, но и по ординалу (или только по ординалу. По крайней мере в OS/2 это было именно так).

Таким образом, можно получит адрес и вызвать функцию, не упоминая ее имя, только некоторый номер. Правда, его тоже можно считать именем... И ее адрес в памяти тоже можно считать именем. Решать вам - это то, что вы хотели или нет :) И вообще - точно скажите, что вы под этим - именем - подразумеваете.

Например, функция в библиотеке в безымянном пространстве имен - но адрес которой возвращает другая функция. Считать ли такую функцию (имя которой вам принципиально неизвестно, но вызвать которую вы в состоянии) безымянной?

Что касается чисто языковых возможностей - то по сути любой объект имеет имя, которое, правда, может быть - как в случае лямбда-выражений - недоступно пользователю.

Но допустим, что такая возможность была бы доступна. Что бы это изменило? Просто имя функции заменилось бы адресом, который бы играл роль этого имени, нет?

Словом, было бы хорошо, если бы вы уточнили свой вопрос, а то, знаете, без точного ТЗ результат один - ХЗ...

Comment: Сейчас тоже, если открывать системные dll, постоянно встречаются функции без имён.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко Да как-то мне сейчас с ними особенно работать не приходится. Вот в свое время под полуосью...

Answer (score 4):

Ну в принципе, так как в С++ можно привести любой тип к любому типу, то можно тупо взять абсолютный адрес памяти и привести его к типу функции. А потом вызвать эту функцию по указателю. Будет как-бы вызов функции без имени. Но только надо знать адрес функции в памяти. В системах типа десктопа знать адрес функции в памяти сложно, но можно (это требует рассмотрения карты памяти, которую генерирует линкер). Во встроенных системах (без MMU, колец защиты и виртуальной памяти) это проще, но тоже требует рассмотрения карты памяти. А можно дизассемблировать свой или чужой код в рантайме и искать какие-то признаки начала функций. А потом передавать туда управление. Хорошее занятие для вирусописателей, кстати.

UPD1:

Опять же в принципе все объекты в программе имеют имя и тип. Это, так сказать, "синтаксический сахар", так как человеку удобнее работать с поименованными объектами. Трансляторы и создавались в том числе для того, чтобы работать с именами, а не с кодами и адресами. Так что в общем случае вопрос должен звучать так: "может ли какой-то объект в программе (функция, массив, структура) не иметь имени". Ответ на этот вопрос - может, но зачем? Можно программировать в кодах и тогда у Вас не будет вообще никаких имен в программе. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Может. Конструкторы не имеют имен:

> **15.1 Constructors [class.ctor]**
>   1 Constructors do not have names.

Comment: Интересно, они вообще считаются функциям (методами)?..

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, считаются. Собственно они же описаны в разделе "Special member functions"

Comment: Во внутренней таблице для линкера (то есть в объектнике) конструктор имеет имя. Да и для программиста конструктор имеет имя, совпадающее с именем класса.

Answer (score -1):

Может.  Лямда-функция.  Обычная не может.
Сама по себе безымянная функция бессмысленна,  так как к ней невозможно будет обратиться. Нужно либо имя, либо какой-то иной механизм вызова. Например,  лямда-функция,  привязанная к указателю на функцию или к слоту (если говорить о qt)

Comment: В С++ нет "лямбда-функций". Есть лямбда-выражения, которые порождают безымянный объект-замыкание. Тот метод данного объекта, который вы потом будете вызывать, имеет имя: это `operator ()`. Имя типа объекта замыкания неспецифицировано, но оно тоже существует.

Comment: @AnT,  не буду спорить,  но я встречал это именно под названием "лямбда-функция". Может быть там,  где я, встречал (форумы и учебные сайты,  названия не запоминал)  использована неверная терминология?  Не знаю,  со стандартом не сверялся.